# pdf of $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}, 0<x<2\pi$

Tags: statistics

Suppose X has a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$, that is,
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}, 0<x<2\pi$$
Consider $Y = \sin^2(X)$

Using the following theorem:
Let X have a pdf $f_X(x)$, let Y = $g(X)$ and define the sample space $\Theta$. Suppose there exists a partition $A_0 … A_k$ of $\Theta$ such that $P(X \in A_0)=0$ and $f_X(x)$ is continuous on each $A_i$.
G(x) = $g_i(x)$, for $x \in A_i$
$g_i(x)$ is monotone on $A_i$
The set $Y = \{y: y = g_i(x)$ for some $x \in A_i\}$ is the same for each $i = 1 … k$
$g^{-1}(y)$ has a continuous derivative on Y, for each $i = 1 … k$ then

$$f_Y\left(y\right)\ =\ \left\{\begin{matrix}\sum_{i=1}^{k}{f_X\left(g_i^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)\left|\frac{d}{dy}g_i^{-1}\left(y\right)\right|,\ y\in Y}\\0,\ otherwise\\\end{matrix}\right\}$$

I find that the solutions that the intervals are:
$A_0 = 0$, $A_1 = (0, \frac{\pi}{2}), A_2 = (\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}), A_3 = (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$, then $g_i(x) = sin^2(x)$ on $A_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Therefore $g_1^{-1}(y) = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{y})$,$g_2^{-1}(y) = \pi - \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{y})$, $g_3^{-1}(y) = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{y}) + \pi$, $g_4^{-1}(y) = 2\pi -  \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{y})$.

However, I wouldn't have figured these out - what's the explanation behind these intervals?

Comment: I assume you have a typo in your intervals. The theorem states that you want the function to be monotonic on the interval. Take a look at the graph of $\sin^2 x$ and you should see that it is increasing from $0,\pi/2$ then decreasing until $\pi$ and so on. Which is why the intervals are split the way they are.

Comment: Sketch $g(x)=\sin^2(x)$ from $x=0$ to $\pi$. You will see that every value between $0$ and $1$ appears four times so $g(x)$ does not have a unique inverse.  In another sense the inverse of $g$ is multivalued, and these four intervals and expressions enable you to find those values

Comment: @Gregory Would you mind sharing how I get $\pi$ in the inverse functions also?